# Java single char String represented by multiple bytes

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have encountered a problem with String comparison. (yes I'm using .equals)
I found that by converting my seemingly identical strings to charArray one has an additional index containing nothing.

Now I took my string apart using substring and getBytes()

```
string.substring(0,1).getBytes()
```

which prints `[-17, -69, -65]`
all other substrings from this string for example:

```
string.substring(1,2).getBytes()
```

print a single array `[100]`

Comment: what is your `string`?

Comment: my string is a String object (sorry... while writing the code I was getting a bit lazy)

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question I found the answer and decided to share in case someone encounters a similar problem.
My problem could be solved by changing the files encoding.

The file was encoded in UTF-8 (according to notepad++) and I saved it as UTF-8 without BOM which removed the special char read from the file.